# How does Warlock Spell slot level interact with the feat Metamagic Adept from Tasha's Cauldron of Everything?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, warlock, metamagic

I have a warlock tiefling for which I am considering to choose the feat Metamagic Adept from *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*. This will get me 2 sorcery points to spend.

1. Looking at the sorcery point system, I believe I could spend these 2 sorcery points to regain one 1st-level spell slot, since a warlock only has a few of these. I imagine this would be helpful. However this is not stated in the feat specifically, only to use two Metamagic options. Is there a source that mentions something about the feat that one could exchange the 2 sorcery points into spell slots as well? Or would someone rule it as possible?
2. If I understand correctly, as a warlock I could only cast spells at a certain level. The reason I am asking is related to the question above. If I am returning 2 sorcery points and get a 1st-level spell slot back. That would be great at lower levels I think. Since a warlock as of 3rd level could only cast spells from level 2, a warlock starting from level 5 casting level 3 spells, etc. Meaning I (most likely) wouldn't prepare a 1st level spell at higher levels. Could I exchange 2 sorcery points for a 1st level spell, but then cast it at a higher level spell since I am a warlock, or is that the reason why the answer to question 1 would be no?

Below the information on sorcery points (Flexible Casting) and the Metamagic Adept feat.

Metamagic Adept feat:

> You’ve learned how to exert your will on your spells to alter how they function. You gain the following benefits:
>
> - You learn two Metamagic options of your choice from the sorcerer class. You can use only one Metamagic option on a spell when you cast it, unless the option says otherwise. Whenever you gain a level, you can replace one of your Metamagic options with another one from the sorcerer class.
> - You gain 2 sorcery points ***to spend on Metamagic*** (these points are added to any sorcery points you have from another source but can be used only on Metamagic). You regain all spent sorcery points when you finish a long rest.

Flexible Casting:

> You can use your sorcery points to gain additional Spell Slots, or sacrifice Spell Slots to gain additional sorcery points.
> Creating Spell Slots. You can transform unexpended sorcery points into one spell slot as a Bonus Action on Your Turn. The created Spell Slots Vanish at the end of a Long Rest. The Creating Spell Slots table shows the cost of Creating a Spell slot of a given level. You can create Spell Slots no higher in level than 5th. Any spell slot you create with this feature vanishes when you finish a Long Rest.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem well enough for a green check?

Answer (score 43):

#### Metamagic Adept does not give the Flexible Casting feature.

[Flexible Casting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#FontofMagic-371) is uniquely a 2nd level feature of the sorcerer class that allows a sorcerer to convert sorcery points into spell slots. *This feature is not a feature of the [Metamagic Adept](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/metamagic-adept) feat*, so a warlock with the feat (or anyone without at least 2 levels of sorcerer) cannot convert sorcery points into any kind of spell or pact magic slot.

#### The sorcery points from Metamagic Adept can only be used for metamagic.

Metamagic Adept clarifies this:

> You gain 2 sorcery points to spend on Metamagic (these points are added to any sorcery points you have from another source but *can be used only on Metamagic*).

The *only* thing you can use your sorcery points for are the two metamagic options you have from the feat.