# How can a 14th level Artificer with the Metamagic Adept feat restore their sorcery points?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, feats, metamagic, artificer

Considering a 14th level artificer with the Metamagic Adept feat in D&D 5e:

- I'm assuming that the feat does not grant the ability to restore sorcery points by expending spell slots (since it doesn't grant the Flexible Casting feature)
- It seems to me that an artificer could use the Bloodwell Vial to regain the sorcery points when they roll a Hit Dice (once before the next dawn), but they would only regain 2 (since that's their maximum amount)
- Are there other items/ways to regain expended points?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### You have found the only way for an Artificer to restore the Metamagic Adept SP apart from a long rest.

A 14th level Artificer has the [Magic Item Savant](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#MagicItemSavant-1134349) feature:

> You ignore all class, race, spell, and level requirements on attuning to or using a magic item.

So a 14th level Artificer may attune to the [Bloodwell Vial](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/bloodwell-vial), which says:

> In addition, when you roll any Hit Dice to recover hit points while you are carrying the vial, you can regain 5 sorcery points.

Since you maximum SP is 2, you would only regain 2.

There is no other way to regain these 2 sorcery points, except through taking a long rest. As noted [in my answer here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/178571/62294), Metamagic Adept does not allow you to convert spell slots into SP.

[This search](https://www.dndbeyond.com/search?q=sorcery%20points&f=backgrounds,classes,feats,races,equipment,magic-items&c=characters,items) on DNDBeyond shows all of the relevant results in their database that mention the phrase "sorcery points". The only results are the Metamagic Adept feat, the Bloodwell Vial, and the Sorcerer class.

You can restore them a little bit quicker [if you are a race that can long rest in 4 hours](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/40734/62294).

(Notably, a 13th level thief rogue could [probably](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/172294/62294) do something similar with their Use Magic Device feature.)

Comment: As was pointed out by The Wizificer, the item's property is limited to once per dawn, so the amount restorable by this method is fairly limited.